# Can I have two colliders attached to my enemy that do different things and if so how?

Tags: unity-game-engine, triggers, collision

Is it possible to have two colliders for one object?

My situation is that I have a `CircleCollider2D` that causes my enemy to chase the player when it enters. This works well but I want to also have a `BoxCollider2D` that will switch scene to my scene called "BattleScene" when the player enters.

I want it so that when my player enters the circle collider my enemy will follow him but when the player gets closer and enters the box collider (both attached to the enemy) it will switch scenes to the scene called "BattleScene".
Another alternative I thought of was using a rigid body collision but I don't know how to implement that.

Here is my code

```
private bool checkContact;
private bool checkTrigger;
public float MoveSpeed;
public Transform target;
public Animator anim;
public Rigidbody2D myRigidBody;
BoxCollider2D boxCollider;
public string levelToLoad;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Transform>();//getting the position of our player

    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    myRigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    boxCollider = gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (checkTrigger == true)
    {

        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime); //move towrds from your position to the position of the player 
        if (myRigidBody.position.y < target.position.y && Mathf.Abs(target.position.y - myRigidBody.position.y) > Mathf.Abs(target.position.x - myRigidBody.position.x)) //if it is  further away from target in x direction than y direction the animation for moving in y is loaded and vice versa
        {
            anim.SetFloat("MoveY", 1); 
            anim.SetFloat("MoveX", 0);
        }
        if (myRigidBody.position.y > target.position.y && Mathf.Abs(target.position.y - myRigidBody.position.y) > Mathf.Abs(target.position.x - myRigidBody.position.x))
        {
            anim.SetFloat("MoveY", -1);
            anim.SetFloat("MoveX", 0);
        }
        if (myRigidBody.position.x > target.position.x && Mathf.Abs(target.position.y - myRigidBody.position.y) < Mathf.Abs(target.position.x - myRigidBody.position.x))
        {
            anim.SetFloat("MoveX", -1);
            anim.SetFloat("MoveY", 0);
        }
         if (myRigidBody.position.x < target.position.x && Mathf.Abs(target.position.y -myRigidBody.position.y)  < Mathf.Abs(target.position.x - myRigidBody.position.x))
        {
            anim.SetFloat("MoveX", 1);
            anim.SetFloat("MoveY", 0);
        }

        anim.SetBool("checkTrigger", checkTrigger); //updating if in range

    }


}
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.name == "Player")
    {
        checkTrigger = true; //setting our check trigger = true so it will follow if in radius
        anim.SetBool("checkTrigger", checkTrigger);
    }


}


public void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.name == "Player")
    {
        checkTrigger = false; //setting our check trigger = false so it will not follow if not in radius
        anim.SetBool("checkTrigger", checkTrigger);
    }
```

EDIT: THIS PROBLEM HAS BEEN RESOLVED

Comment: Yes it's possible, but you need to add an empty game object to enemy and attach a boxcollider to it, then add script to this gameobject for triggerEnter and then send a message to parent script(enemy) to navigate to battle scene

Comment: Not sure but maybe you could even check something like `if(other.GetType() == typeof(BoxCollider2D)) ... `

Comment: Thankyou to the pair of you. I am fairly new to this in unity so some code for this would be greatly appreciated. @derHugo

Comment: @Hesamom the above comment applies to you too

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this is by having an empty GameObject with the other collider attached to it, while making sure **both** GameObjects have a Rigidbody - the child with IsKinematic ticked. Why? Because this will separate the child GameObject from the parent collision structure. Read more about [compound colliders](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html).

You should only have more than one collider in one GameObject if they all make part of the same collision structure. If they have different purposes, use different GameObjects with kinematic Rigidbodies, each handling it's own task.

In your specific scenario, I would have the CircleCollider in the enemy itself and the BoxCollider in a child GameObject with a kinematic Rigidbody. This child GameObject can also contain a script with the sole purpose of checking against the Player and loading the BattleScene.